# DownloadFileAsync Error

Tags: c#, .net

I keep get this error while trying to download a file using `WebClient.DownloadFileAsync`

> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An
>   unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOException:
>   Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established
>   connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An established connection was
>   aborted by the software in your host machine
>   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at System.Net.PooledStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at System.Net.Connection.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)
>   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)

The code:

```
try
{
    client.DownloadFileAsync(URL, location);
    client.Dispose();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: press ctrl+c on message box to copy the error message and paste it here instead of uploading it's picture.

Comment: can you give us the url and location parameter?

Comment: Well i'm not sure how to do that, in java i use synchronized(OBJECT_LOCK).... to avoid those kind of errors but in c# i'm still learning so could you be more clear if you don't mind
And okay the link is the code http://pastebin.com/mPNsyrXC

Comment: try testing your code with known file url. maybe the url is incorrect

Comment: That actually worked for me, thanks alot where i can give rep if that possible :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in the URL you supplied to the `DownloadFileAsync` method.
try double checking the URL, test it with a known URL that exists.